# Supplemental canon material to Lost Girl tv show

Tags: lost-girl

I just finished watching the Canadian T.V. series Lost Girl and am feeling bit... lost. Plot points and character motivations seemed to vanish between episodes which made me wonder if I was missing some kind of supplemental canon material where these gaps are explained. So my question is: Are there any canon web series, books, comics, spin-offs,  missing episodes, etc. that occurred before or during Lost Girl's T.V series?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The show enjoyed a limited set of four [**webisodes**](http://lostgirl.wikia.com/wiki/Category:Webisodes);

- [UPYURS6](http://lostgirl.wikia.com/wiki/UPYURS6)
- [Red Tape](http://lostgirl.wikia.com/wiki/Red_Tape)
- [Getting to Know You: The Una Mens](http://lostgirl.wikia.com/wiki/Getting_to_Know_You:_The_Una_Mens).
- [Prophecy](http://lostgirl.wikia.com/wiki/Prophecy)

A set of six **[Motion Comics](http://lostgirl.wikia.com/wiki/Lost_Girl:_The_Interactive_Motion_Comic)**;

- [Chapter 1: Feed](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X8ZpTRV1DGM)
- [Chapter 2: Leftovers](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aTnJUSIGXHI)
- [Chapter 3: Futakuchi-onna](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dzommkIMCwY)
- [Chapter 4: Dead Leads](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z55-A6agzx0)
- [Chapter 5: Inhuman](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hXHq0NCQQlI)
- [Chapter 6: Reset](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YxRc4XHXfMk)

The show had a **tie-in comic**. It received a very limited release but the entire thing is online on the wiki.

- [Lost Girl: Prologue.](http://lostgirl.wikia.com/wiki/Lost_Girl:_Prologue)

The show had an [**interactive mobile game**](http://lostgirl.wikia.com/wiki/Lost_Girl:_The_Game) available on both Android and iPhone. Neither are available on their respective stores, but you can find them on all good APK and iPhone archive sites.

The show also had an **[interactive website](http://web.archive.org/web/20101110005047/http://lostgirlseries.com/)**, alas now defunct.

The show had (has) a **[twitter page](https://twitter.com/lostgirlseries)**. During premiere and finale episodes, the showrunners would live-tweet, often sharing additional information with superfans.